# How to allow jackson to trade \uXXXX as plaint text?

Tags: json, unicode, jackson

I use jackson to parse json data. Now I have a problem with handling a \uXXXX issue.

The data I got here is like

```
{"UID":"here_\ud83d\udc3b"}
```

After I use `ObjectMapper.readValue(jsonContent, UserId.class);` to convert json to an instance of UserId, the UID property is not literally "here_\ud83d\udc3b". Jackson convert `\ud83d\udc3b` to 2 chars as the unicode value.

My question is, is it possible to let jackson skip this "Unicode transformation" and key the literal value "\ud83d\udc3b" as it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent ObjectMapper from converting escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573452/how-to-prevent-objectmapper-from-converting-escaped-unicode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. JSON parsers are required to handle Unicode escapes to produce underlying Unicode characters.

When writing, on the other hand, some characters may also be encoded using similar Unicode escapes.

So if you need to use escaping, you need to re-encode such values yourself.