# How to prevent ObjectMapper from converting escaped unicode?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I'm using Jackson 2.4 in Java to do some JSON legwork. I make a call to a remote server with Apache HttpGet, deserialize the results with Jackson into a POJO, manipulate those results, and then serialize them with Jackson to push back to a remote server with HttpPost.

The issue I'm finding is that Jackson is translating unicode literals into unicode characters, which I need it not to do thanks to encoding issues on each end. For example, I might have this in the JSON:

```
"field1": "\u00a2"
```

But Jackson is converting the "\u00a2" to "¢" when it's deserialized, which causes problems with the remote server. It has to be maintained as escaped unicode. If I use something like Apache EntityUtils (specifying UTF-8) or even make the call from my web browser to get the data, the escaped unicode is preserved, so I know that it's coming in properly from the server. If I have Jackson consume the input stream from the entity on the response, it does the conversion automatically.

I've tried writing with a JsonGenerator that is explicitly set to UTF-8 to write to the HttpPost. It didn't work, remote server still rejected it. I've dug through the configuration options for ObjectMapper and JsonParser, but I don't see anything that would override this behavior. Escaping non-ASCII, sure, but that's not what I need to do here. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't get Jackson to deserialize this string without replacing the escaped unicode.

EDIT: Well, my bad, the only literals having problems have 3 or 5 leading slashes, not just one. That's some screwiness, but Java seems to be what's unpacking it by default during the deserialization, even if the raw text that came back from the server preserves it. Still not sure how to get Java to preserve this without checking an insane amount of text.

Comment: How's your deserialization defined?

Comment: Just to get the most obvious out of the way: If `"\u00a2"` is somehow part of your Java code then the Java compiler is doing the convertion not Jackson. If you want notate the string consisting of 6 chars you must use `"\\u00a2"`.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the JSON using the correct character set? How do you get the JSON text from the `ObjectMapper` and how is that text sent on to the remote server? Did you encode it in UTF-8 on that transmission? Did you tell the remote server what character set you sent it in? --- However, if the remote server cannot handle UTF-8, or whatever character set you're actually using, and you want to stick to US-ASCII and JSON escapes for the rest, have `ObjectMapper` output the JSON text as a `String`, and then convert non-ASCII to escapes yourself before sending it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are expecting is outside scope of Jackosn. It's java that converts the String while reading it. For same reason, if you have a properties file with value `\u00a2` and read it using jdk API, you will get converted value. Depending on the file size, either you can double escape char \ before passing the string to Json or "escape" the string back using your Deserializer (only for string) and something like below:

Thank you

```
package com.test.json;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class Jackson {

    static ObjectMapper _MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"field1\": \"\\u00a2\",\"field2\": \"\\u00a2 this\",\"numberField\": 121212}";
        SimpleModule testModule
                = new SimpleModule("StOvFl", _MAPPER.version()).addDeserializer(String.class,
                        new UnEscapedSerializaer());

        _MAPPER.registerModule(testModule);

        Map m = _MAPPER.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
        System.out.println("m" + m);

    }
}

class UnEscapedSerializaer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String s = jp.getValueAsString();
        return org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(s);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to custom Jackson's behavior is customized `JsonParser`. See jackson's source code of [JsonFactory](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonFactory.java), [ReaderBasedJsonParser](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/ReaderBasedJsonParser.java);

The key methond is `_finishString2()` which is used to do 'decodeEscaped', so we can write a JsonParser extends ReaderBasedJsonParser and override the `_finishString2` method:

```
public class MyJsonParser extends ReaderBasedJsonParser {
    @Override
    protected void _finishString2() throws IOException {
        char[] outBuf = _textBuffer.getCurrentSegment();
        int outPtr = _textBuffer.getCurrentSegmentSize();
        final int[] codes = _icLatin1;
        final int maxCode = codes.length;

        while (true) {
            if (_inputPtr >= _inputEnd) {
                if (!loadMore()) {
                    _reportInvalidEOF(": was expecting closing quote for a string value");
                }
            }
            char c = _inputBuffer[_inputPtr++];
            int i = (int) c;
            if (i < maxCode && codes[i] != 0) {
                if (i == INT_QUOTE) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    //c = _decodeEscaped();
                    //do nth
                }
            }
            // Need more room?
            if (outPtr >= outBuf.length) {
                outBuf = _textBuffer.finishCurrentSegment();
                outPtr = 0;
            }
            // Ok, let's add char to output:
            outBuf[outPtr++] = c;
        }
        _textBuffer.setCurrentLength(outPtr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"field1\": \"\\u00a2\",\"field2\": \"\\u00a2 this\",\"numberField\": 121212}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new MyJsonParserFactory());
        Object o = objectMapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Full demo code [here](https://gist.github.com/tianzhipeng-git/2997a5afb44efc3308b5e59e8bf45971)

Answer (score 0):

Spent a few hours looking for a solution, and I found it.

I had some Binary data. for example `0xab 0xa6 0xaa`
I wanted my json to look like this:

```json
{
  "binary-data-as-unicode": "\u00ab\u00a6\u00aa"
}
```

The reader of this json would get rid of the `\u00` and treat what's left as a hex string representing binary data.

In order to use jackson ObjectMapper, I prepared a String object with my formatted unicode notation string of hex data:

```
public static String toHexString(ByteArrayOutputStream stream) {
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : byteArray) {
        hexString.append(String.format("\\u%04X", b & 0xFF));
    }
    return String.format("\"%s\"", hexString.toString());
}
```

Then, I used:

```
// stream of type ByteArrayOutputStream
String unicodedString = toHexString(stream);
ObjectNode objNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
objNode.putRawValue("field-name", new RawValue(unicodedString));
```

This way, there was no further escaping, and I got what I wanted.