# How to receive raw json string from Rabbit in Java without any modifications?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, rabbitmq

I have a spring boot app configured with a RabbitMqListener. It has to receive JSON data of the format below: (showing sample)

```
{ "name" :"abc",  
"key" : "somekey",
"value" : {"data": {"notes": "**foo \u0026 bar"}}** 
}
```

This data represents some info. which should be used only for read-only processing, and the receiver spring app should receive it as it is(raw form).

What I mean is if I assert `value` node in spring app with input that was published on queue it should be equal.

This is simply not happening.
I always get the value in spring app as
`foo & bar` but I wanted it in raw form without a conversation of \u codes.

I try several approaches,

> 1. Jackaon2JsonMessage converter,
> 2. passing bytes from `Message.getBody() - byte[]` to `mapper.readValue()` in Rabbit handler.
> 3. Using JSON-simple, gson libraries

Why is it so tricky to get the data as it is, without any conversion or translation.
Do I need to follow an alternative approach?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicitly enabling the escaping of non-ascii characters on your `ObjectMapper`?

```
mapper.getFactory().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but Its not working.. btw JsonGenerator is deprecated. I created mapper as: mapper=JsonMapper.builder().enable(JsonWriteFeature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII).build()

Comment: Hmm now that I read your question again I think your problem lies at the deserializer, and not the serializer. Does this answer help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46579378/546967

Comment: tried that before posting here.. it works for the example given there but for the sample I posted, where the \u00xx chars are nested somewhere, it doesn't work.. may be I need to tweak something.. Its strange why the built-in JsonWriteFeature is not working..

Comment: The `JsonWriteFeature` (or deprecated `JsonGenerator`) are settings for the JSON *serializer*, which is responsible for transforming a Java Object Model into JSON. Your problem lies with the *deserializer*, which is responsible for transforming JSON into a Java Object Model. Unfortunately there's no `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII` equivalent for the `JsonReader` part of the equation. I think writing a custom `JsonDeserializer` is probably the best way forward.